# Using mongodb in a daily service

Tags: mongodb

I have a service that parse a online document every day.
I'd like to store that on a Mongo database.
The data extracted is organized like that (I have a process list every day) :

```
public class Process
{
    public IList<Lawyer> Lawyers { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Info AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to store everyday a List of Processes.
My client application will read that database and search all processes of given lawyer of that day and show like a email app.

How can I structure my mongodb to that ?

---

I will have between 6k and  10k processes per day. 
Daily document has processes for every lawyer from my state
Each lawyer will have at most 50 processes per day.

So I will have a web application like gmail where a lawyer will see all his processes.

Processes will be erased every month (or 2), but I need to keep the processes from my clients forever, or until he trash it.

So my initial idea was to move client processes to another(?) database that is consumed by 'gmail' app.

So, if the processes are from my actual clients I keep it (move?)
If it is from a non client I erase after 1 month.

What you guys think?

---

Thanks

Comment: That's a tricky question. Indeed, there is multiple solutions to your problem. What about making a single collection to store Processes ?

Comment: Will it be a good solution performance wise when I need to find all process that have lawyer.id = 123 ?

Comment: Again, there is multiple solutions. It depends on your input and your output I think. Filtering by lawyer is not really bad (in term of performance or programming skills). Can you tell us how many processes you want to retrieve from a single query ? So we can see if it is feasible or not.

Comment: I edited the question with your question

Comment: So yes, it is feasible with a single collection. Do you need anything else ?

Comment: Please clarify: How many new processes will a lawyer get each day? Will these accumulate forever, be replaced from scratch every day, or cycle out after some age? What's the greatest number of processes a lawyer might have? How much data is in a process?

Comment: I edited my question with some additional data

Comment: Ok, so, your best option is to create a single collection to store Processes. In that way, you can save your processes for an infinite period of time and make a query for your app easily (based on lawyers and dates).

Comment: I wouldn't bother moving client processes to a different structure, just tag them with a binary flag. Then it still takes just one query to grab everything, and you can use the flag to put some sort of visual indicator on the display. (And also use it in a where clause to exclude it from being cleaned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo is not intended to be used in a relational context. Your use case doesn't seem very relational, so it seems a good fit. Rather than the classic "one table for lawyers and one for processes" I would simply make a single collection for lawyers, with one of the attributes in the object being named "processes" and containing a list of process objects. Since you're always going to be querying all the processes of a lawyer (if I've understood that correctly,) it requires only a single query.

```
{
    id: '12345',
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    address: '123 Main St.',
    phone: '123-456-7890',
    processes: [
        {
            name: 'process 1',
            ...: ...
        },
        {
            name: 'process 2',
            ...: ...
        }
    ]
    ...: ...
 }
```

Comment: Not possible that way. He says he will have 10k processes per day. So, it means a lawyer will have an infinite number of processes after some days, weeks. Mongodb cannot handle document with a large size (your processes list will be too big). I prefer to stay with my answer which is a collection of processes. Moreover, I think he prefers the service to respond with a list of processes, the core of the app, and so the main collection. Am I right ?

Comment: I read that as 10K overall per day, not 10K per lawyer per day. And I'm not assuming that processes accumulate under each lawyer, but that they are replaced daily. <shrug> I don't know what a process is in this context. YMMV.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that way. I think every processes will be added to mongo every day, no trash. So, that's why I thought a Process collection is better. Still depend on the need.

Comment: Yeah, it's vague, I've asked OP to clarify.

Comment: Note, since you might have up to 3000 processes per lawyer, and the max doc size is 16M, that gives you a worst case of 5K per process. So maybe do some analysis of your current data set and figure out what your averages and maximums might be.